# VBA Dynamic XY Series plotting

Tags: excel, vba, plot

I have some code that is supposed to plot multiple series of data to a single chart all from 2 columns (X and Y values) of data. I have it currently set up such that the if statement checks the "ID" that is constant for a single series in another column of data, and will plot a new series once the "ID" changes to signify a new series, and will then plot to the chart.

The code will cycle through, and I can watch it plot each series I want on the chart, however after executing the chart will only have the last of the series in the two columns plotted. I can check the chart afterwards and see the series have been generated, but all of them are dataless aside from the last in the column. Below is my code and I appreciate any comments.

```
    For i = datastart To dataend
            If ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value <> ws1.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value Then
                    Z = i - k + j
                    t = i - k + 1

                    With Chart5
                       .PlotArea.Select
                       .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                       .SeriesCollection(t).Name = ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value
                       .SeriesCollection(t).XValues = "=Data!$G$" & Z & ":$G$" & i
                       .SeriesCollection(t).Values = "=Data!$F$" & Z & ":$F$" & i
                    End With
                    j = i
            Else
                    k = i
            End If
       Next i
```

I am currently at just getting this functioning.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    ' ... some other code

    .SeriesCollection.newSeries
    t = .SeriesCollection.Count
    .SeriesCollection(t).Name = ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value
    .SeriesCollection(t).XValues = "=Data!$G$" & z & ":$G$" & i
    .SeriesCollection(t).Values = "=Data!$F$" & z & ":$F$" & i

    ' ... some other code
```